# iTunes 11 search library on description no longer works

Tags: itunes, search

I upgraded to iTunes 11 and the search functionality appears to have changed.  I can't search by the Description of a track, which was useful when searching through a library of TV shows that we have saved.

How do I get back the ability to search by the description?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the search magnifying glass, I clicked off "search entire library" and then iTunes would perform the search on the description.  Works great.